# lxml fromstring() yields HTML code with &#13; everywhere

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I'm reading in a webpage from the intranet via

```
        webpage = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(self.URL))
        doc =  webpage.read()
        root = html.fromstring(doc)
```

I noticed that I can't read anything via findall() from this root Object, I then looked into the root Object via:

```
code = etree.tostring(root)
```

which yielded me the exact HTML code but with

> `&#13;`

everywhere in the Code. I think this might cause my parsing issues (I hope so at least).

How can I get clean HTML code out of this? Any encoding/decoding needed?

I've tried to decode it to UTF-8, but that didn't work appearantly.

```
print code.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, that wasn't the issue.

The problem was that I downloaded the site and parsed it offline, where it sneaked in

< tbody >

tags that I used in my Xpath queries. This caused my script not to work when downloading the website fresh via lxml.